# How to use PM2 CLI on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, pm2

I'm trying to use `pm2` on Heroku. I did have a look at the [documentation](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/use-pm2-with-cloud-providers/#heroku-google-app-engine-azure). It looks like the application works fine once deployed, and the logs indicates that multiple instances has started on a 2X dyno.

Yet when I run: `heroku run bash` and do a `pm2 ls` I get an empty list:

```
┌──────────┬────┬──────┬─────┬────────┬─────────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ mode │ pid │ status │ restart │ uptime │ memory │ watching │
└──────────┴────┴──────┴─────┴────────┴─────────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
```

And I can't use any `pm2` CLI functions. I understand that when I do a `heroku run` command a one-off dyno is created on the fly and the `pm2` instance running on this dyno does not run any process.

However I don't see how I can access `pm2` on a specific dyno.

Is there any way to take advantage of the `pm2` cli on Heroku?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the Heroku docs,

> your app is spread across many dynos

As a result there isn't one place your app is running so I can't see how you will be able to do what you want.

[Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#ssh-access) explain this a bit more.

Answer (score 2):

`heroku run` connects you to an additional temporary container.

To connect to a real running app container, use `heroku ps:exec`.

Comment: this worked for me, can see all 8 processes. thanks!